# Google Maps v3 event click in cycle

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have problem with script, can someone help me?

```
//Add event to google maps click => open marker.infobox
   for(var marker in markersWithArray){
       var lastInfoWindow; //Get lastInfoWindow for close google maps infowindow
       var markerI = markersWithArray[marker]; //Get marker from loop
       var infoWindow = markerI.infoWindow; //get infoWindow from marker, work prefectly
       console.log(infoWindow) // => all time good, object with
                               //    info box. All time unique id and content.

       google.maps.event.addListener(markerI, 'click', function() {
           console.log(infoWindow); //Problem here, object too, but id and content have 
                                    //a last value what recorded on top (console.log) 
                                    //last value of cycle
           if(lastInfoWindow)
               lastInfoWindow.close();
           infoWindow.open(map, this);
           lastInfoWindow = infoWindow;
       });
    }
```

Can anyone tell me how to get value in cycle to event "google.maps.event.addListener" ??
Thx :).

Comment: When you did `var lastInfoWindow; marker = ` you realize you just overwrote the global marker variable, right? I think you meant to put a `,` after `lastInfoWindow` instead of an `;`

Comment: `marker = markersWithArray[marker];` likely a problem too. Try mixing up your variable names and not using same `marker` all the time

Comment: Wow, this is fast ans. Yes, I want rewrite variable **var marker** as a real marker in object..

Comment: **I was update solution, but same problem**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your marker has an infowindow as a property (I don't think it is a documented property, but your question implies it exists), this should work:

```
   google.maps.event.addListener(markerI, 'click', function() {
       console.log(this.infoWindow);
       if(lastInfoWindow)
           lastInfoWindow.close();
       this.infoWindow.open(map, this);
       lastInfoWindow = this.infoWindow;
   });
```

Comment: I love u, my besty :D. I cant get u +1 but thank u so much :D